# Playing a WAV File Multiple Times

Tags: android

I need to have the same short wav file (1 second) play each time the user presses a single button. I have the following code that works for about 30 clicks and then the app "Force closes" on the device. I think what is going on is that new instances of media player are being created and then the instances build up (approx 30 clicks) and the app crashes. So I then added the "release" instance in the hope that on button-click the wav would play and then the mediaplayer would be released. However, it doesnt work that way. With the mp.release() no sound is played possibly becaue the medaiplayer gets released too soon for the user to hear the sound?

Anyone have a good tip to help me getting this to work? Thank you all so much.

Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
       button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
      public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.clicker);
            mp.start();
            mp.release();
```

Comment: Have you checked the logcat to find the exact reason for the crash? And, you seem to have answered your own question :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple just create the MediaPlayer once, and play it over time.

```
 private MediaPlayer mp;
 public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            if (mp == null){
                 mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.clicker);
            }
            mp.start();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use MediaPlayer, when SoundPool is better suited for small audio files? As a base you could use this:

```
this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);


soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 70);

final HashMap<Integer, Integer>  soundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

final int soundID = 4;
soundPoolMap.put(soundID, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.wav_sound, 4));

soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() 
{
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) 
    {
        if (sampleId == 4)
        {
            soundPool.play(4, 50, 50, 1, 0, 1f);                                
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution that will work

```
MediaPlayer mp;
mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.clicker);

 public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            if(mp.isPlaying())
                {
                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
                mp.release();
                }
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.clicker);
                mp.start();
```

This is will check if mediaplayer is already playing..If it already playing it will stop and release it and then initialize that mediaplayer(mp) object and start the mediaplayer.

If it is not playing it will execute the code after the if statement and the start the media player after initialzing the mediaplayer object(mp in this case)

To learn more about MediaPlayer study this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html. Study the Mediaplayer life cycle